# Updating a CoreData record using MagicalRecord creates an additional empty record

Tags: ios7, magicalrecord

I have an iPad app that uses MagicalRecord to manage my CoreData store.  When I do an update to a record, in addition to the record being updated, I also get an empty record.

**UPDATE:** This is an image of the entity in question:

[image]

And of ClientInfo:

[image]

This is an image of the empty record:

[image]

This is the code that creates the update:

```
if(updateFlag == NO)  //  record has been pre-loaded to enable update
    ai.aApptKey = selectedClientKey;  //  new key

ai.aStartTime = selectedStartDate;
ai.aEndTime= selectedEndDate;
ai.aServiceTech = boStaff.text;
ai.aServices = soServices.text;
ai.aNotes = soNotes.text;
ai.aImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(oApptImage.image, 1.0);
ai.aPosX = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: x];  //  indicates column start
ai.aPosY = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: fOffsetFromShopOpens + (iNumberOfSegments*2)];  //  appointment start slot in points.y
ai.aPosW = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 214.0];
ai.aPosH = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (intEndTime - intStartTime)];  //  appointment height in grid units (25 per each 15 minutes)

//    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];  //  store it...
[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];  //  store it...
```

I was using MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion, and decided to change to MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait, and I get the same result.  What I'm afraid of is one of my users running out of room on their device.  Any ideas?

Comment: What may be your problem is that your new record has a required relationship, and so creates an entity automatically to fill the spot without your knowledge.

Comment: That's interesting... let me update the question with the entities in question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely, you're creating an empty object in that same context. It shows up in the data base because it's there when you called save. Look for your calls to mr_createEntity or mr_createInContext: and see what's actually created. You can also break on that save point in your code and run the following in lldb:

```
po [context insertedObjects]
```

Look at the result set. If one of the objects isn't what you expect, then you're, again, likely creating a blank object beforehand somewhere.

Comment: Hi Saul... no, there is no call to either of the MR_create methods; when I call MR_saveToPersistentStore... however, I did find that I was creating a new context in several places which I deleted (I have a localContext defined in AppDelegate.h.  I tried to use *[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext: localContext];*, but got an error stating **no known class method** (I even imported the .h file).. any other suggestions?

Comment: How are you inserting objects in the first place? The MagicalRecord way is with one of those methods. Are you using a different creation/insertion method? Look for the default core data way. The bottom line is MagicalRecord cannot know what your objects are and does not create any data for you. Duplicate data means you have duplicate objects being created somewhere in your code.

Comment: The default object insertion method to look for would be + (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context on NSEntityDescription.

Comment: Saul:  I don't insert objects programmatically; I use XCode 5.  However, I'm wondering if the *relationships* would have anything to do with it.  When first building the entities, I thought I might need them, but I never used them; so, I'm thinking of removing them and see what happens.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Maybe we're talking about a different Core Data...how do you get data into the data store? You do it by creating instances of objects. There is no other way I'm aware of to put data in a Core Data store than via code...

Comment: I think we're talking about apples and oranges here.  I use MR exclusively, staying away from Core Data proper (been there, done that! Before I found MR, I used FMDB with SQLite).  Anyway, I think I solved my issue -- I just do a search on all records that have *null* in the key, and delete them.  Thanks for your time tho', I know you're busy... :D

Comment: It still sounds like you're create an object with nil values somewhere. the insertNewObjectForEntityForName method and MR_createInContext methods do the exact same thing, namely, insert data into the store. It will always be the case that to create data you will use one of these methods. The next logical step in your scenario means that you are creating nil values somewhere and haven't found out where. You should never have to go back and delete nils. No part of either framework creates data for you.